# Javascript Hide-Unhide HTML Text Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide & un-hide html text box when selecting another select value using JavaScript.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#pf_status', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  console.log(val);
  if (val == 2) {
    $('#ref-col').hide();
  } else {
    $('#ref-col').show();
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ref-col').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>
            Pass Fail Status <span class="text-danger">*</span>
        </label>
    <select class="form-control" name="pf_status">
      <option value="1">Pass</option>
      <option value="2">Fail</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3" id="ref_col">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Pass Date</label>
    <font style="font-size: 14px; color: #AA0000"></font>
    <input type="text" name="pass_date" id="pass_date" class="form-control" value="somedate">
  </div>
</div>
```

I did not get the desired output. I think something going wrong. Can any one help me ?

Comment: You have select with name attribut and trying to access it with id selector: `$(document).on('change', '#pf_status'` change  it to: `$(document).on('change', 'select[name="pf_status"]',`

Comment: What is your desired output? Can you give us a picture or a detailed description of what you want to see, and what isn't right?

Comment: A `name` is not an ID. Voting to close as typo

Comment: `name="pf_status"` this is a problem, it should be `id="pf_status"`

Comment: also `$('#ref_col').toggle(val!=2)` - use the same dash in the selector as in the ID, and you can toggle instead of using if/show/hide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with your selector you are selecting the drop-down with a name using a `#` sign:

and there's also a problem with your selector `#ref-col` in your JS it should be like this `#ref_col`

change your name to `id="pf_status"` in your HTML like this and this will work:

```js
$(document).on('change', '#pf_status', function() {

  var val = $(this).val();
  
  $('#ref_col').toggle(val!=2)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>
      Pass Fail Status
      <span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </label>
    <select class="form-control" id="pf_status">
      <option value="1">Pass</option>
      <option value="2">Fail</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3" id="ref_col">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Pass Date</label>
    <font style="font-size: 14px; color: #AA0000"></font>
    <input type="text" name="pass_date" id="pass_date" class="form-control" value="somedate">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for pointing out, that's a typo I'll update that

Comment: But still with remaining the issue

Comment: also `$('#ref_col').toggle(val!=2)`

Comment: @mplungjan I updated my answer Thanks for this `$('#ref_col').toggle(val!=2)` much better approach. and removed `displayed:none` from html so div is show by default as first selected value is `Pass` by default

Comment: See my solution for a more elegant handling of value at load time

Comment: @mplungjan Sure, Let me have a look

Answer (score 2):

1. Spelling the selector the same as the ID
2. ID not name is used in the script
3. No need to delegate if not dynamic
4. Dropdown does not have a "please select" so trigger the change on load of the page

```js
$(function() {
  $('#pf_status').on('change',function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#ref_col').toggle(val != 2);
  }).trigger("change"); // trigger to handle the lack of "Please select"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>
      Pass Fail Status <span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </label>
    <select class="form-control" id="pf_status">
      <option value="1">Pass</option>
      <option value="2">Fail</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3" id="ref_col">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Pass Date</label>
    <font style="font-size: 14px; color: #AA0000"></font>
    <input type="text" name="pass_date" id="pass_date" class="form-control" value="somedate">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is quite a good way to handle this situation +1 for this :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using ID selector in your JQuery and declared as name attribute in your form

```
<select class="form-control" name="pf_status">
```

either change it to     `<select class="form-control" id="pf_status">`

or

Use the name selector `$(document).on('change', 'select[name="pf_status"]'` in JQuery selector.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#pf_status', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  console.log(val);
  $('#ref_col').toggle(val!= 2)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group"><label>Pass Fail Status <span
                                        class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <select class="form-control" id="pf_status">
      <option value="1">Pass</option>
      <option value="2">Fail</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3" id="ref_col">
  <div class="form-group"><label>Pass Date</label>
    <font style="font-size: 14px; color: #AA0000"></font>
    <input type="text" name="pass_date" id="pass_date" class="form-control" value="somedate">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited a suggested typo... Which you did not notice at all. ( FYI @mplungjan ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You should always try to figure out why the code it is not working.
Always check your browser console, There you will get errors with line numbers.
This way you will learn to master coding with time.
And don't worry about negative rating for your question.WE are developers to push ourselves to create, develop and design for the betterment of the world.

```
JQUERY:

$(document).on('change','#pf_status',function(){
    // Here you are using this object to refer to something that is not available in DOM.
});
```

In your HTML, use id attribute for the select element.And this will work fine.
Well that is already shown above.I will show you  how to setAttribute in javascript for your code without changing any code in your HTML.So that you learn.

In Javascript:

```
let ps = document.getElementsByName('pf_status');
ps[0].setAttribute("id","pf_status"); // if you have only 1 select element in your document
```

There surely are other issues in your code that are all sorted out by other developers.

Comment: Indeed there are no console errors.My statement was  more of a  general one only.As is evident from my words.   **"This way you will learn to master coding with time."**  YOU are a MASTER SIR...I have enormous respect for you. :)